# How to hide a window using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two windows, I want to hide the one that is executing the opening of the 2nd window.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isVisible;
    public bool isVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            _isVisible = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("isVisible");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {            
        Window1 X = new Window1();
        isVisible = false;
        X.Show();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string name)
    {           
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="isVisible" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
</Window.Visibility>
```

The new window is showing however the one that is supposed to get hidden is still there and I can't manage to understand why it's happening.

Comment: A view model shouldn't create a window directly, especially not in its constructor. Use a window service to create windows.

Comment: I'm actually opening a window using a button command, I created a new project just for testing. Either way, do you have an idea on why it's not hiding?

Comment: You haven't assign viewmodel to window as datacontext:

X.DataContext = this;

Comment: @ElBarrent why would that do anything If X is the new form and not the current one

Comment: @Telez Sorry, misunderstood your question. Anyway, check if this viewmodel is assigned to main window.

Comment: @ElBarrent it is.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, you must set `Mode=TwoWay` when binding the `Visibility`.
I don't know why WPF need an explicit declaration like that but I tested and worked.

```
<Window.Visibility>
    <Binding Path="isVisible" Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
</Window.Visibility>
```

Comment: By default all binding are OneWay. To change default behavior of DependencyProperty you have to specify default binding mode via FrameworkPropertyMetadata.